# Как изменить размер картинки через CSS?

Tags: css3, html5

Создаю копию данного сайта `https://codepen.io/freeCodeCamp/full/RKRbwL`. Хочу разместить картинку ниже в левом верхнем углу, как показано на сайте, с сохранением соотношении сторон. Параметры width и height не имеют эффекта в разделе class или img. Как можно сделать? Спасибо большое.

[image: Original Trombones]

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Product Landing Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">

        <!--Top Section-->

        <div class="logo">
            <img src="trombones.png" alt="trombones">
        </div>
        <div class="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li>Features</li>
                <li>How It Works</li>
                <li>Pricing</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <!--Main Section-1-->

        <div class="intro">
            <h2>Handcrafted, home-made masterpieces</h2>
            <form action="#">
                <input type="email" class="email" placeholder=" Enter your email address">
                <button type="submit" class="primary_btn">Get Started</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="line-1">
                <i class="fa fa-fire fa-3x"></i>
                <div class="text-container-1">
                    <h2>Premium Materials</h2>
                    <p>Our trombones use the shiniest brass which is sourced locally. This will increase the longevity of your purchase.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="line-2">
                <i class="fa fa-truck fa-3x"></i>
                <div class="text-container-2">
                    <h2>Fast Shipping</h2>
                    <p>We make sure you receive your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="line-3">
                <i class="fa fa-battery-full fa-3x"></i>
                <div class="text-container-3">
                    <h2>Quality Assurance</h2>
                    <p>For every purchase you make, we will ensure there are no damages or faults
                       and we will check and test the pitch of your instument.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="video">
        </div>

         <!--Main Section-2-->

        <div class="offer">
            <div class="offer1">
                <div class="offer-title1">
                    <h3>TENOR TROMBONE</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="price1">
                    $600
                </div>
                <div class="info1">
                    Lorem ipsum. <br>
                    Lorem ispum. <br>
                    Lorem Ipsum dolor. <br>
                    Lorem ipsum. <br>
                </div>
                <button class="secondary_btn1">Select</button>
            </div>
            <div class="offer2">
                <div class="offer-title2">
                    <h3>BASS TROMBONE</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="price2">
                    $900
                </div>
                <div class="info2">
                    Lorem ipsum. <br>
                    Lorem ispum. <br>
                    Lorem Ipsum dolor. <br>
                    Lorem ipsum. <br>
                </div>
                <button class="secondary_btn2">Select</button>
            </div>
            <div class="offer3">
                <div class="offer-title3">
                    <h3>VALVE TROMBONE</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="price3">
                    $1200
                </div>
                <div class="info3">
                    Plays similar to a Trumpet. <br>
                    Great for Jazz Bands. <br>
                    Lorem Ipsum dolor. <br>
                    Lorem ipsum. <br>
                </div>
                <button class="secondary_btn3">Select</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--End-->

        <footer>
            <div class="terms">
                <ul>
                    <li>Privacy</li>
                    <li>Terms</li>
                    <li>Contact</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="copyright">
                &copy; 2016, Original Trombones
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato&display=swap');

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-color:#eee;
    font-family: 'Lato';
    color: #000000;
}

.container {
    height: 100%;
    width:95%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.container .logo {
   width:50%;
}

.container .logo. img{
    height: 50%;
    width:50%;
}
```

Comment: На картинке должен быть класс. Пишите `'Имя класса'{width: 100px !important; height: 100px !important; }`

Comment: то есть используйте `!important`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если какой то атрибут не работает значит в коде есть атрибут 'важнее' его. Что значит важнее? Например если писать `width` и в теге и в css то будет работать то что в теге потому что он считается 'более важный'. Чтобы изменить этот порядок и заставить программу читать именно этот атрибут используйте `!important`. Если около атрибута написана `!important` он считается главным и выполняется именно он.

---

Пример:

```css
div
{
    width: 100px !impotant;
}
```

Comment: Так плохо всё написано :-( `если писать width и в теге` - это называется inline-стиль. Вы по какой-то причине не упомянули про каскадность css... Вот [ссылочка](https://idg.net.ua/blog/uchebnik-css/azy-css/kaskadnost) с полезной инфой, особенно начинающим. Просто часто замечаю что верстают и пользуются инлайном или id селекторами и вот этими вот !important.

Comment: @Nilsan Я не профи по css поэтому если вы можете объяснить лучше вы можете сделать собственный ответ. И я не обижусь если он примет ваш ответ а не мой. :-)

Comment: Мне кажется будет лучше если просто немного перефразируете свой :-)
П.С. Я просто в суть вопроса не вникал если честно то просто увидел ваш ответ и вот :-)

Comment: @Nilsan предложите правку моего ответа и я приму